# wkhtmltopdf background-image problems

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf in a Rails app and trying to set a border by placing an image with just borders as the background-image for another. (I'm doing this because box-shadow is not working for wkhtmltopdf). This shows up fine in the HTML view, but in the pdf it doesn't work.
My CSS is here:

```
.box{ 
  background-image: url('/assets/posts/background_border.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px; 
}
```

Please let me know how to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make the URL for the background image absolute.

```
background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/assets/posts/background_border.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and finally i solved it.
I get

```
 Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
```

from wktohtml

To solve just remove quote from url declaraion, absolute url is also required. 
So change

```
 background-image: url('/assets/posts/background_border.jpg')
```

To

```
  background-image: url(http://absolute_url_to_image_without_quote)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may have something to do with the image not being loaded at the time the PDF is being generated. I use the command line tool and circumvented the problem using ie.:

```
--javascript-delay 3000
```

NB: This workaround has successfully been tested with relative and absolute paths with or without protocol + domain name.

See possible relating GitHub issue "[wkhtmltopdf background-image not working](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2054)".

Answer (score 0):

You must provide absolute path for the resources.
like /Users/projectname/assets/posts/background_border.jpg in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Use page option: print-media-type

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt